# How do I get (with PHP) the differentials from Phabricator using conduit

Tags: api, phabricator, conduit

Can you help me with a working example on how to get differentials in Phabricator using conduit?

I'm trying to write a script to get a list of differentials from Phabricator based on different criterias (such as status, per-user etc). I've seen there is a package for api connections to Phabricator named conduit (https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabdev/article/conduit/), but although a ConduitClient class is provided (https://secure.phabricator.com/diffusion/PHU/browse/master/src/conduit/ConduitClient.php$3), no indications about the way to use it are given (also the class is dependent upon some external classes). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to use the ConduitClient to create a new task. You should be able to call any conduit method using the same method:

```
<?php
require_once '/your/path/to/phutil/src/__phutil_library_init__.php';

// first you need to connect:

$client = new ConduitClient('https://your_phabricator_instance');
$params = array(
  'certificate' => 'your conduit certificate from  https://your_phabricator_instance/settings/panel/conduit/',
  'client' => 'mytestclient',
  'clientVersion' => '1.0',
  'user' => 'your username',
  'host' => 'https://your_phabricator_instance'   // do not add path!
);
$client->callMethodSynchronous('conduit.connect', $params);


// then you can call methods:

$params = array(
  'title' => 'test task',
  'description' => 'test task'
);
$client->callMethodSynchronous('maniphest.createtask', $params);
```

Replace the path in `require_once`, the certificate, hostnames and user with the correct values and it should work.
If there is something wrong you get an exception with detailed information.

A list with methods to call and which parameters are possible is available on your phabricator instance at `https://your-phabricator-instance/conduit`

Oh, and if the API returns something it is returned by `$client->callMethodSynchronous()` so you can do something like `$result = $client->callMethodSynchronous(...)`

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Some tips on minor roadblocks I hit: __phutil_library_init__.php is from phutil, which is a separate source tree than phabricator. Also, I went into phabricator and added a new bot user, then edited that user's settings, and got the certificate from there. I was previously trying to use my own certificate (which doesn't work, since the user doesn't match)

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on rve's answer, so he deserves the props!

Phabricator's API changed a little bit, so the `conduit.connect` has to be adapted. My part of the script looks like this:

```
$conduitSignature = 'your conduit certificate from  https://your_phabricator_instance/settings/panel/conduit/';
$clientName = 'bot-client';
$clientVersion = '1.0';
$clientUser = 'bot';
$authToken = time();
$authSignature = sha1( $authToken . $conduitSignature );

$client = new ConduitClient('https://your_phabricator_instance');
$params = array(
  'client' => $clientName,
  'clientVersion' => $clientVersion,
  'user' => $clientUser,
  'authToken' => $authToken,
  'authSignature' => $authSignature
);
$result = $client->callMethodSynchronous('conduit.connect', $params);
```